# How to customize PATH for sensu client?

Tags: bash, shell, sensu

I have a sensu client, I debugged its PATH in one of my check script, and it shows:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc/sensu/plugins:/etc/sensu/handlers
```

How can I customize this PATH for sensu, say: I want to add /usr/local/bin to the end of the PATH, which results in:
  /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc/sensu/plugins:/etc/sensu/handlers:/usr/local/bin

I've tried many ways but didn't success, I've tried:

1. Set sensu user's SHELL to /bin/bash (instead of the default /bin/false), and add .bashrc|.profile under sensu user's home dir /opt/sensu, with this line: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`
2. Edit /etc/default/sensu, add this line `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`
3. By reading this: https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/clients, I set `USER=ec2-user` in /etc/default/sensu, after restarting sensu client, I clearly see the sensu client process is running by ec2-user, however, surprisingly, the PATH is NOT the same as ec2-user

All 1,2 and 3 above didn't work, in my check script written in python, I have those lins:

```py
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE
import os
import sys
import shlex

import platform
print os.environ["PATH"]

proc = Popen(['which', 'python'],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate() #does not return until the process has terminated.
print(out)
print(err)
#print(platform.__dict__)
print(platform.python_version())

proc = Popen(['whoami'],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate() #does not return until the process has terminated.
print(out)
print(err)
sys.exit(0)
```

The output was:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc/sensu/plugins:/etc/sensu/handlers
/usr/bin/python   
2.6.6 
ec2-user
```

Update, while I wrote this line in my python check script:

```
proc = Popen(['bash','--login', '-x'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```

I saw it output:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc/sensu/plugins:/etc/sensu/handlers:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

However, the other output surprisingly.... "which python" -> /usr/bin/python, "python --version" -> 2.6.6

Request help....

Answer (score 0):

So do you try to add the PATH in `/etc/default/sensu`

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

https://github.com/sensu/sensu-build/blob/master/sensu_configs/upstart/sensu-client.conf#L30

`. /etc/default/sensu` will make it work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I did try this, but didn't work for me, I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you modify the upstart job to set the path before the sensu-client starts?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line

- export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

in "**/etc/sysconfig/sensu-client**". Create the file if not there. Restart your client and your path will be updated.